# How to integrate swagger with koa and joi?

Tags: node.js, swagger, koa, joi

I am writing node API based on **KOA** framework. For validation I prefer **Joi** validation and add a middleware. Now I want integrate **Swagger**. But I think that I write the same part of code twice (request data validation part, one in joi validation , another in swagger yaml file). Please, give me an **example** or the best way to integrate swagger, koa and joi.

Comment: this project is just doing what you asking for : https://github.com/zaaack/koa-joi-swagger